# How to download CSV via terminal (SSH)?

Tags: csv, curl

I'm trying to download the Chicago Crime stats data (CSV format) from their government website. This is the link for download:

```
https://data.cityofchicago.org/api/views/ijzp-q8t2/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD
```

but it only works when you copy it to the browser and hit enter.

I am wondering how to download the csv file on terminal? Can I use:

```
curl -O https://data.cityofchicago.org/api/views/ijzp-q8t2/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD > Chicago.csv
```

I want to save the Chicago.csv to my current work directory on ssh.

Comment: Have you tried the curl command you suggested? If so, did you get any errors?

Comment: btw, you're above works... but it took AGEEES to get going...

Comment: Use either `-O localfilename` or `> localfilename`, not both.

Comment: yes, I tried my own way, but because the file is so big. I don't know whether it works until the download finishes. I didn't see any errors when I do curl -O https://data.cityofchicago.org/api/views/ijzp-q8t2/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD > Chicago.csv

Comment: use either `curl -o outputfile.csv http://path/to/file` or `curl http://path/to/file > outputfile.csv`. -o <file> `Writes  output to <file> instead of stdout`, -O `Writes output to a local file named like the remote file we get`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your command works, however it take a long time to "compute" the file, which is huge (5360469 rows, and after 215 MB downloaded, I only got 881705 rows, so the final file size should be about 1.3GB).

If you try with another set (let's say "Flu Shot Clinic Locations - 2012", 1058 rows, 192kB) you can see that your command works perfectly, even if it does not write to Chicago.csv.

Take a look at man page:

```
-o, --output <file>
          Write  output to <file> instead of stdout.
-O, --remote-name
          Write output to a local file named like the remote file we get. (Only the file part of the remote file is used, the path is cut off.)
```

When you use the following command:

```
curl -O https://data.cityofchicago.org/api/views/ijzp-q8t2/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD > Chicago.csv
```

The data is written to `rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD`, stdout remains empty, so Chicago.csv file will remain empty.

Instead, you should use either:

```
curl -o Chicago.csv https://data.cityofchicago.org/api/views/ijzp-q8t2/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD
```

Or:

```
curl https://data.cityofchicago.org/api/views/ijzp-q8t2/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD > Chicago.csv
```

Answer (score 3):

have you tried `wget`? like this:

```
wget --no-check-certificate --progress=dot https://data.cityofchicago.org/api/views/ijzp-q8t2/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD
```