# Tableau - how to load csv data directly from URL

Tags: csv, tableau-api, import-from-csv

I would like to pull "Most+Recent+Cohorts+(Treasury+Elements).csv" from this [site](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/college-scorecard) directly into Tableau.

How could I do this?

I tried:

data >> new data source >> connect to text file >> entered the URL - https://s3.amazonaws.com/ed-college-choice-public/Most+Recent+Cohorts+(Treasury+Elements).csv

But nothing happened

I tried web data connector but nothing happened :(

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like there is a native option to do it in Tableau (currently using version 9.3.2).

However, you could download the csv file using terminal/command line. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19453773/how-to-download-csv-in-terminal-ssh).
Once the file is downloaded, you can point Tableau to this file on your disk.
The csv file could also be regularly refreshed (downloaded) by scheduling `cron` or Windows Task Scheduler to run your csv-downloading script.

The same question was previously asked in Tableau's [forum](https://community.tableau.com/thread/121097) so you might want to consult it for other suggestions.